# Sorting a matrix rowname based on column of another matrix

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, row

I have two matrices similar to below:

```
a b c d             id1   id2  id3   id4
1 2 3 4              b     1    2    3
6 7 8 9              c     0    2    4
                     d     1    2    2
                     a     5    6    8
```

The expected out put is as follow :

```
     b c d a
[1,] 2 3 4 1
[2,] 7 8 9 6
```

And I want to sort the row name of the left matrix according to the first column (id1) of the second matrix.
Does anyone has any suggestion that how can it be processed ?
I was simply trying "first matrix"[colnames("second matrix"),]. but it was not that easy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
first_mat[,second_mat[, 1]]

#     b c d a
#[1,] 2 3 4 1
#[2,] 7 8 9 6
```

**data**

```
first_mat <- structure(c(1L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 9L), .Dim = c(2L, 
  4L), .Dimnames = list(
  NULL, c("a", "b", "c", "d")))

second_mat <- structure(c("b", "c", "d", "a", "1", "0", "1", "5", "2", "2", 
  "2", "6", "3", "4", "2", "8"), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
   NULL, c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4")))
```

Comment: Dear Ronak, Thanks for your answer! for some reasons the solution does not work properly! It sorts not accordingly and it also creates duplicates. for example a-1 b-1. Do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @Amir can you update your post with your expected output ?

Comment: Dear Ronak, The output that you mentioned is what I expect but applying the code on my matrices does not results into similar sorting

Comment: @Amir then you need to post an example which is more closer to your actual matrices. It would be difficult to guess without that.

Comment: Dear Ronak, I coudl figure out the problem.. I should have used first_mat[, row.names(second mat)]

Comment: @Amir I see.  So actually it was not the first column but your row names. I am glad you were able to solve it in the end. :)